# To get the root path of file in java

Tags: java, jsp, jar

I am using eclipse Indigo IDE ..I am developing a jsp application (**myProject**) using eclipse in which i have a property file (**myProject\webcontent\db.properties**) for configuring database credentials.

I am trying to access this file from a class (**myProject\src\samplePackage\sampleDBConnect.java**). I have exported **samplePackage.jar** into **myProject\webContent\WEB-INF\lib**.

I have a Test.jsp page which calls a method in sampleDBConnect.java.

When i am trying to run this Test.jsp page, the current directory path shows **C:\Documents and Settings\username**.  I have my project in some other drive(E:).

Can someone tell me how to access the properties file....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
```

This assumes your db.properties is in the same directory "samplePackage".

If you want to keep it in src directory or say resource directory then use

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
```

Since your java code belongs to the same web project you don't have to create a jar of the same project and place that in the WEB-INF/lib folder

Answer (score 1):

move db.properties to myProject\src dir,
java code:
InputStream input = sampleDBConnect.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db.properties");